# Hide the url of embedded video

Tags: php, youtube-api, embed

How can I hide the embedded video URL in my html page source with php or scripts ?

e.g. the embedded link of youtube or google video, i want to hide the video id or the link

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/(hide video id)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I don't believe you can. If the link is in the source code, people can see it.

Comment: If you hide it, how can the browser know what to request from YouTube in order to put the video into your page?

Comment: I'm not sure but here's a sample http://watchwildboyz.blogspot.com/search/label/Season%201 any ideas ?

Comment: @user3533628 That's not a video hosted on YouTube.  That's a video file hosted on Google Drive that the owner has allowed users to view.

Comment: @user3533628 the embedded video link isn't even hidden, you can see it in plain HTML: ```<a href="rtsp://v5.cache6.googlevideo.com/ChoLENy73wIaEQkCB4wjKhxl2xMYDSANFEgDDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp" type="video/3gpp"><img width="407" height="339" alt="video" src="http://video.google.com/ThumbnailServer2?app=blogger&amp;contentid=db651c2a238c0702&amp;offsetms=5000&amp;itag=w160&amp;sigh=ePZdy2e73WvBe1hxiPfrPpGCVnY" class="BLOG_mobile_video_class" id="BLOG_mobile_video-db651c2a238c0702"></a>```

Comment: Can't a user just right-click the video anyway, and just copy the URL from the context menu?

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. Your browser wouldn't know what to play if the URL would be hidden.

Everything your browser has to see, the user can see too.