# Is there a way to privately embed a HTML5 file in a website?

Tags: html

I am looking to embed a HTML5 file on a webpage and keep its source hidden.
Originally, I used an iframe, however, anyone could go directly into the webpage's source code and copy the iframe's src, and then paste it as a webaddress, and be taken directly to the non-embedded version. The embedded version is important to me for the site's layout. 
Is there a way for me to disable access to the iframe's src file (which I seriously doubt as then the iframe presumably wouldn't work), or do you have a recommended alternative?

Thank you

Comment: No, that's not possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide the url of embedded video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293474/hide-the-url-of-embedded-video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. This is not possible.

Even if there was a possibility to prevent the browser from displaying the source code, it would still be possible to view the raw HTML code by just sending a raw HTTP request.

The only possibility is to just not sending the HTML-Code. But without HTML, no content is displayed. The browser can only display any content based on the HTML code.